# SJF - When the shortest job is the last one

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture

I know what SJF is, how it works but I have a dubt on this situation (see the image) and 2 questions that I hope you could help me with:

1) Do I need to start with first process (A in my case) every time even if is not the shortest one?

2) What if the sortest job is the last one (G). Do I need to start with it, return to top, check all of them, find the next shortest one that will be F and so on?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DarJb.jpg

Sorry for posting the image like this, I'm new here and I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: could you post some code instead?

Comment: I don't have anything implemented yet. I want to have all possible situations covered and to be sure that I'm using the algorithm correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that you are using SJF preemptive algorithm.
1) In this case at time t=0, only A has arrived so you have to execute it.
 At t=1, B has also arrived. Now shortest of two jobs(A and B) is executed since A(=2) is the shortest one so it will be executed first.
At t=2, no process has arrived so A will continue its execution. So on...

The idea is processor will run the shortest of all the arrived jobs first.

2)When process G will arrive , if it will be shortest of all remaining jobs then it will be executed first.